# Order of Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle Books

Tags: suggested-order, larry-niven, jerry-pournelle

I finished reading (or listening since it was an audio book) to Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle's *Mote in God's Eye*.

And I was wondering if there is a suggested order to read their books? Plain chronological or is there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most Niven & Pournelle collaborations are stand-alones, and can be read in any order.

They do have some works with sequels.  In almost all cases, the first book was originally stand-alone, and the sequel came out years later.

## The Moties

1. [*The Mote in God’s Eye*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye) (1974)
2. [*The Gripping Hand*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gripping_Hand) (1993)

## The Burning City

1. [*The Burning City*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Burning_City) (2000)
2. [*Burning Tower*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Tower) (2005)

## Heorot

1. [*The Legacy of Heorot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legacy_of_Heorot) (1987)
2. [*Beowulf’s Children*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf%27s_Children) (1995)

## Inferno

1. [*Inferno*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_%28novel%29) (1976)
2. [*Escape from Hell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Hell_%28novel%29) (2009)

## Unrelated Works (no particular order)

- [*Fallen Angels*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_Angels_%28science_fiction_novel%29) (1992)
- [*Footfall*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footfall) (1985)
- [*Lucifer’s Hammer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer%27s_Hammer) (1977)
- [*Oath of Fealty*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Fealty_%28novel%29) (1981)

---

Jerry also wrote a number of works leading up to *Mote* in his CoDominium/Empire of Man universe.  Most of them are part of the [Falkenberg’s Legion saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince_%28Pournelle%29), which is set roughly 900 years before *Mote*:

1. *West of Honor*
2. *The Mercenary*
3. *Prince of Mercenaries*
4. *Go Tell the Spartans*
5. *Prince of Sparta*

   Note: The book *Falkenberg’s Legion* is a compilation of *West of Honor* and *The Mercenary*.  The book *The Prince* is a compilation of the entire saga.

[*King David’s Spaceship*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_David%27s_Spaceship) takes place more or less simultaneously with *The Mote in God’s Eye*, but is pretty much stand-alone.

Comment: I believe *The Burning City* and *Burning Tower* are set in the same universe as Niven's *[The Magic Goes Away](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Goes_Away)* and it's associated shorter works. Can anyone tell us if one needs to read the earlier works to read the *Burning* novels?

Comment: @neilfein, they are, but _Burning City_ wasn't my taste. I only read a few chapters. so I can't really say.

Comment: Yeah, me too. (mustaddmorecharacters)

Comment: Jerry Pournelle's daughter Jennifer wrote a sequel to _Mote_ called _Outies_ (no, the title is not very original!). I like it better than _The Gripping Hand_ but not as much as _Mote_. FWIW.